# Can I access specific parts of this dictionary where the keys are the same?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm accessing an API and retrieving some data from the API as a dictionary where the keys are all the same. Code below.

```
order_book = session.orderbook(symbol="ETHUSDT")
print(order_book)
```

This returns the below dictionary. A Range of prices, the symbol name (which is always the same), how many contracts are available at the price and the side available as buy or sell.

```
{'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': [{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.55', 'size': 99.62, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.5', 'size': 4.93, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.45', 'size': 6.45, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.4', 'size': 6.39, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.35', 'size': 32.81, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.3', 'size': 17.89, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.25', 'size': 4.41, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.2', 'size': 26.39, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.15', 'size': 15.35, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.1', 'size': 23.01, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.05', 'size': 37.36, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125', 'size': 62.45, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.95', 'size': 0.01, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.9', 'size': 6.25, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.85', 'size': 12.03, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.8', 'size': 48.02, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.75', 'size': 10, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.7', 'size': 0.01, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.65', 'size': 4.6, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.6', 'size': 4.17, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.55', 'size': 24.44, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.5', 'size': 16.72, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.45', 'size': 2.68, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.4', 'size': 8.87, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1124.35', 'size': 135.25, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.6', 'size': 21.38, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.7', 'size': 0.02, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.75', 'size': 9.46, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.8', 'size': 0.01, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.85', 'size': 29.1, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.9', 'size': 4.26, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1125.95', 'size': 14.53, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126', 'size': 13.9, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.05', 'size': 21.66, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.1', 'size': 39.36, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.15', 'size': 24.7, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.2', 'size': 9.07, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.25', 'size': 4.08, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.3', 'size': 49.79, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.35', 'size': 9.66, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.4', 'size': 17.13, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.45', 'size': 11.72, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.5', 'size': 4.55, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.55', 'size': 4.58, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.6', 'size': 124.11, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.65', 'size': 1.86, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.75', 'size': 18.47, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.8', 'size': 3.42, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.85', 'size': 18.46, 'side': 'Sell'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1126.9', 'size': 27.71, 'side': 'Sell'}], 'time_now': '1655855941.823052'}
```

So I am trying to figure out how I can access specific contract size for specific prices when the keys are the same? For example, the first 5 buy side and the first 5 sell side contract size, or even individual contract sizes based on specific prices.

I have tried googling this but I'm not even sure what to google to be honest.

Any help would be vey much appreciated. Even some idea on what I could search to figure it out myself?

Thanks in advance for any help.

****Edit:****

okay so I'm trying to use the code posted below to find the largest value contract size of the buy side

```
transactions = [trans for trans in order_book['result'] if trans['size'] == max and trans['side'] == 'Sell']print(transactions)
```

I'm receiving the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15204/2875214528.py in <module>
 12 order_book = [session.orderbook(symbol="ETHUSDT")]
 13 ---> 14 transactions = [trans for trans in order_book['result'] if trans['size'] == max and trans['side'] == 'Sell']
 15 print(transactions)TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

again any help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** (Based on OP's comment that `order_book` is a `list` of `dict`, not just a `dict`.)

```py
def find_largest_contract(order_side, order_book):
    largest_contract = float('-inf')
    for order in order_book:
        for result in order['result']:
            if result['side'] == order_side:
                largest_contract = max(largest_contract, result['size'])
    return largest_contract
```

**OLD VERSION**

```py
def find_largest_contract(order_side, order_book):
    largest_contract = float('-inf')
    for result in order_book['result']:
        if result['side'] == order_side:
            largest_contract = max(largest_contract, result['size'])
    return largest_contract
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(find_largest_contract('Buy', order_book))
>>> 135.25

>>> print(find_largest_contract('Sell', order_book))
>>> 124.11
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. when using the above code I get the following error. Its an error I have come across before.
####
---> 15     for result in order_book['result']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: can you verify the input data is correct? ```TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str``` this error means that we are passing a ```string``` to ```list index```. But as per your sample data, ```order_book``` is a ```dict```. When I copied your sample ```order_book``` and ran the code, it works.

Comment: the order book variable returns a list of a dictionaries. I'm not sure if this helps but i think the output is also in JSON as its coming from a API

Comment: your sample input is just ```dict``` not a ```list``` of ```dict```. So, we are having the issue. I updated the solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: sample for the list of dictionaries the order_book variable input will output when printed      [{'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': [{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1050.25', 'size': 4.61, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1050.1', 'size': 4.76, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1050', 'size': 0.32, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1049.95', 'size': 12.99, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1049.9', 'size': 0.2, 'side': 'Buy'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '1049.85', 'size': 3.79, 'side': 'Buy'},

Comment: I updated the solution, can you check if it works?

Comment: wow that works! thank you so much for your help! i really appreciate it. Do you offer private lessons? if so what's your hourly rate? thanks heaps

Comment: There are bunch of free and good resources online to learn from. You can give try to those resources. Best wishes :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `result`, which is a list of dictionaries, rather than a dictionary.

The lazy way would be with a list comprehension

```
transactions = [trans for trans in order_book['result'] if trans['size'] > 30]
transactions = [trans for trans in order_book['result'] if trans['side'] == 'Buy']
transactions = [trans for trans in order_book['result'] if float(trans['price']) < 1125.4 and trans['side'] == 'Sell']
```

Comment: added your code to the above question, thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: if order_book is structured the same as in your question this should work. I've updated price because it's actually a string in result